# Windows Phone textbox auto sugest from webpage javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8, textbox, windows-phone

Hello in a windows phone webapp I would like to add auto suggestions to the text box as the user types.
On the website this done by
 `<input id="search_single" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:E.searchPage.textSuggestion();">`

Is there a way to get these suggestions and then show them on the windows phone textbox?
Thanks

Comment: You don't get `onkeyup` events? What about `onkeypress`?

Comment: when on the website yes the `onkeyup` fires fine, my problem here, and I might not have explained that correctly, is that im trying to create a more native non web experience so i would like the auto suggestions that i can get on the webpage to also show on the windows phone xaml textbox. :-)

Comment: I'm probably stating the obvious here but: check the Windows phone xaml textbox API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows phone i usually use AutoCompleteBox control from [windows phone toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) to acheive a behavior like TextBox with auto suggestion. You can set AutoCompleteBox's ItemsSource to a Collection propety in the model, and populate that property with data from anywhere (web service, local database/storage, etc). These are totarials i found after quick googling [link1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/autocomplete-in-windows-phone-7/), [link2](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Auto_Complete_Box_in_Windows_Phone).